# Laravel cannot retrieve data from multiple model with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, eloquent

Hi I am beginner with Ajax at the Laravel. I wanted to fetch data with Laravel Eagerload function to my blade modal.

This is my Expenses Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'surname',
    'email',
    'password',
    'status',
    'role',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];

public function Expense () {

    return $this->hasMany(ExpensesModel::class);
}
```

This is my Expenses Model
`

{
use HasFactory;

```
protected $table = 'expenses'; 

protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'emp_id',
    'expense_input_date',
    'expense_type',
    'expense_category',
    'reason',
    'status'

];



public function UserExpense () {

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,   'emp_id' );
}
```

My controller

```
This is My controller function
  public function edit (Request $request) {

        $req_id = array('id' => $request->id);
    
        if($request->ajax()) { 
           
            $employee  = ExpensesModel::with('UserExpense')->where('id' ,$req_id)->first();
           
            return response()->json($employee);
          
        }
     
    } 

This is my blade script
` 

 function editFunc(id){
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "{{ url('/expenses/advancedtable/edit') }}",
    data: { id: id },
    dataType: 'json',

  
    success: function(res){
    $('#EmployeeModal').html("Edit Employee");
    $('#employee-modal').modal('show');
    $('#id').val(res.id);   
    $('#emp_id').val(res.name);
    $('#expense_input_date').val(res.expense_input_date);
    $('#expense_type').val(res.expense_type); 
    $('#expense_category').val(res.expense_category);
    $('#expense_slip_no').val(res.expense_slip_no);
    $('#expense_amount').val(res.expense_amount);
    $('#currency').val(res.currency);
    $('#description').val(res.description);


}
});
}
```

I tried everyting but it does not work. I wanted to retrive user name from User Model by using foreign key on the Expenses model emp_id.

is there something I missed somewhere can you help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is controller?

Comment: Your Relationship is wrong , Expense model you have to use user class & user model you have to use expense class

Comment: Khk Rzk 
I am using user class in expense model 
public function UserExpense () {

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,   'emp_id' );
}

Comment: Amir Khan
 public function edit (Request $request) {

        $req_id = array('id' => $request->id);
    
        if($request->ajax()) { 
           
            $employee  = ExpensesModel::with('UserExpense')->where('id' ,$req_id)->first();
           
            return response()->json($employee);
          
        }
     
    }

Answer (score 0):

Here how its work.
First of all change relationship in your User and Expenses model like this.

```
// User Model
public function userExpense() {
  return $this->hasMany(ExpensesModel::class,'emp_id','id');
}

// ExpensesModel
public function user() {
  return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id','emp_id');
}
```

Then change your controller function.

```
// controller function
public function edit (Request $request) {
  $req_id = $request->id;  
  $employeeExpense = ExpensesModel::with('user')->where('id' ,$req_id)->first();
  return response()->json($employeeExpense);
}
```

Then change your ajax sucess function.

```
// ajax sucsess function
success: function(res) {
  console.log(res); // to view your response from controller in webbrowser's console
  $('#EmployeeModal').html("Edit Employee");
  $('#employee-modal').modal('show');
  $('#id').val(res.id);   
  $('#emp_id').val(res.user.name); // it will print user name
  $('#expense_input_date').val(res.expense_input_date);
  $('#expense_type').val(res.expense_type); 
  $('#expense_category').val(res.expense_category);
  $('#expense_slip_no').val(res.expense_slip_no);
  $('#expense_amount').val(res.expense_amount);
  $('#currency').val(res.currency);
  $('#description').val(res.description);
}
```

when you use 'with' eloqunt method it will add relationship function name to your query result, so you want to get user details then you should be do like `res.user.userfield` this is applicable for hasOne only.

For other relationship you will refer to this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships